# Large images move when browser resizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, responsive-design

So On my webpage I have a number of large images which can be seen as you scroll down. They display fine on my normal sized browser, however when I shrink the size of the browser, the white space between the images increases quite drastically. I would like the white space between the two images, however I do not want the gap between them to change and enlarge. The same is present for the about section at the top as when the browser resizes, the about section's white space increases and the gap between it and the image below enlarges.

I am trying to make my website responsive (hence the %) however it isn't working too well right now so I might stick to making a normal website. However, any useful responses whatsoever will be greatly appreciated!!!

```css
html {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 overflow: scroll;
}

.about {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50%;
 background-color: #fffff;
 position: absolute;
}

.about h1 {
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: 900;
 font-size: 50px;
 color: #00b4ff;
}
.about p {
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 30px;
 margin-right: 30px;
}

.books {
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 top: 990px;
 z-index: -2;
 background-position: center;
}

.business {
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 top: 1800px;
 z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css"/>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900,400italic,700italic,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>  
</head>

<div class="about"> 
   <h1>ABOUT</h1> 
   <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
    labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
    nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt 
    in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum <br><br>
    ed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, 
    totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta
    sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur
    magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, 
    consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
   </p>
  </div>
  <img class="books" src="http://delightedimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Delighted-Images_Nicole-and-Ryan_Joshua-Tree_Engagement_82_0406.jpg" alt="books"/>
  
  <img class="business" src="http://nikonrumors.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Nikon-1-J5-sample-images-4.jpg" alt="business"/>
 </div><!-- /container -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use absolute position to place your images. Either build yourself flex-containers for the images using  tags or else use margin-top, and margin-bottom tags to define the white space between your  elements, and use the browser's normal layout to your advantage. The following will set the top image to appear exactly as it appears in your design, but sets spacing between the two images by using margins, dynamically changing image size to match the window width. If you want more white space or less, just change the margin number for the second image. If you want the distance to be relative to screen size instead of pixel size, use a percentage instead.

```
.books {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    margin-top: 990px;
    z-index: -2;
    background-position: center;
}

.business {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    margin-top:100px;
    z-index: -2;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/pjgbp7jo/

Comment: Thanks so much!! Small query, how would I remove the white space to the left and right sides of the images?

Comment: You should be able to do that by defining margin-left: 0%; margin-right: 0%;

The standard is that if right is undefined it receives left's value, but I've had cases where that didn't work, so I normally define both if I need either.

Answer (score 1):

Your images have those huge whitespace because you have them absolutely positioned. If you want your images to display on top of each other make them `display: block;` instead of absolutely positioning them. Or, if you make your images fixed width, they will not resize and you won't have those whitespaces.

Comment: I have a slideshow at the top of my page (using skippr) so when I set the images to 'display: block;', they all become hidden under the slideshow so I cant see them on the page anymore. I want them to display one after the other after the slideshow, not beneath it.

Comment: wrap the slider with a `div` with `clear:both;` css.

Answer (score 1):

why you did not using flexbox?!

```
    .container {display: flex;flex-direction:column;}
    .about {
        background-color: #fffff;
        height: 50%;
    }

    .about h1 {
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 900;
        font-size: 50px;
        color: #00b4ff;
    }
    .about p {
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: 30px;
        margin-right: 30px;
    }

    .books {
        height: auto;
        z-index: -2;
        background-position: center;
    }

    .business {
        z-index: -2;
    }
```

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you this is great!! How would I remove the white space to the left and right sides of the images though? I dont want white space there haha

Comment: yes, sorry i'm busy! use `align-items:center` in css code of container